# how to create Highstock with stock tools in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, highcharts

I'm trying to change my chart type based on `dropdown` in `Highsghcharts/Highstock` with stock tools in a  Angular 6 project. Could you please help me by giving an example to work on it or if there are any examples in javascript but there is nothing with Angular.

Comment: which chart you want to implement?

Comment: iam implementing highstock with stock tools

Comment: could you plz help me to create highstock with stock tools in angular with example ?

Comment: Do you want different highstock charts on the same data set?

Comment: _yes_ i'm looking for that only

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Here is an example of how to implement the stock tools GUI in Angular. With that, you should be able to add some features and indicators base on current data. Is that what you had in mind? https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-6ly2j